# Defining compile-time Comparable objects with Boost.Hana

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++14, boost-hana

I am struggling with having user-defined types as keys in a `hana::map`. 
I run into a `static_assert` saying that the comparison must be possible at 
compile time. I did implement `constexpr bool operator==` for combintations 
of (I believe) all of them. What's the problem? Since my `operator==` is `constexpr`, my objects should be comparable at compile-time, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must return an `integral_constant<bool, ...>` from your comparison operator, not a `constexpr bool`. The following works:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <int i>
struct UserDefined { };

template <int a, int b>
constexpr auto operator==(UserDefined<a>, UserDefined<b>) 
{ return hana::bool_c<a == b>; }

template <int a, int b>
constexpr auto operator!=(UserDefined<a>, UserDefined<b>) 
{ return hana::bool_c<a != b>; }

int main() {
    auto m = hana::make_map(
        hana::make_pair(UserDefined<0>{}, std::string{"zero"}),
        hana::make_pair(UserDefined<1>{}, 1)
    );

    assert(m[UserDefined<0>{}] == "zero");
    assert(m[UserDefined<1>{}] == 1);
}
```

**Why?**

To understand why a `constexpr bool` comparison operator is not enough, consider a pseudo-implementation of `hana::map::operator[]`:

```
template <typename ...implementation-defined>
struct map {
    template <typename Key>
    auto operator[](Key const& key) {
        // what now?
    }
};
```

Inside `operator[]`, the *type* of the returned value depends on the key. We must somehow extract a `bool` representing which value is associated to that key, but that `bool` must be known at compile-time (i.e. be a constant-expression) for the return type to depend on that. So inside `operator[]`, we need a `constexpr bool` representing whether `key` is the key associated to a given value of the map. However, since there's no way to specify the fact that `key` is a `constexpr` parameter, we can't extract a `constexpr bool` from that argument, even if `Key` has a `constexpr bool operator==` defined. In other words,

```
template <typename Key>
auto operator[](Key const& key) {
    // impossible whatever some_other_key_of_the_map is
    constexpr bool found = (key == some_other_key_of_the_map);

    // return something whose type depends on whether the key was found
}
```

The only way to achieve the above is to do something like

```
template <typename Key>
auto operator[](Key const& key) {
    constexpr bool found = decltype(key == some_other_key_of_the_map)::value;

    // return something whose type depends on whether the key was found
}
```

and hence require that `Key::operator==` returns an `IntegralConstant`. There's more information about this and related notions [here](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/#tutorial-algorithms-cross_phase) and [here](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/#tutorial-appendix-constexpr).